# Scafolding a new backend application with lb4

Tags: loopback

I am trying to create a new backend application with "lb4 app", but it fails saying that **it cannot find _.gitignore file** in the new application folder. (this folder is created within the scafolding process

LOG messages:

srueda@Sergios-MBP Css-projects % lb4 app
? Project name: natour-backend
? Project description: natour backend
? Project root directory: natour-backend
? Application class name: NatourBackendApplication
? Select features to enable in the project Enable eslint, Enable prettier, Enable mocha, Enable loopbackBuild, Enable vscode, Enable docker, Enable repositories
, Enable services
node:events:368
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/srueda/Desktop/Css-projects/natour-backend/_.gitignore'.**

```
at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
at exports.readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js:18:20)
at Object.safeCall [as safe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:24:8)
at DirectoryReader.readNextDirectory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:78:10)
at Readable.DirectoryReader.stream._read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:57:18)
at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:496:27)
at readdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/index.js:27:21)
at Function.readdirSyncStat (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/index.js:34:10)
at ReaderSync.dynamicApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:64:24)
at ReaderSync.api (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:56:25)
```

Emitted 'error' event on Readable instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
errno: -2,
syscall: 'scandir',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: '/Users/srueda/Desktop/Css-projects/natour-backend/_.gitignore'
}

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too when using Node 17.2.0, and I solved it by using the latest LTS (16.13.1) instead.

Comment: Worked for me! To install Node 16.13.1 on Ubuntu, run: 
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`